# Как сделать все карточки одинаковой высоты?

Tags: html, css, materialize-css

Как сделать все карточки одинаковой высоты, без применения **`max-height`**

что бы было понятно , нужно развернуть пример кода на всю станицу

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form class="col s12 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" novalidate="">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6"><input class="ng-tns-c40-0 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" data-length="10" id="input_text" name="str" type="text" ng-reflect-name="str"><label class="ng-tns-c40-0" for="input_text">search</label></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="transition: all 13s;">
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/d1b/98e1c-61c8-11e1-865f-00259036a114.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">клей для плитки; крестики; затирка для швов; плиткорез;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/9b5/7ac1c-02a7-11e5-afe5-00259036a192.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">рулетка; нож; клей Thomsit; клей для линолеума; клей для напольных покрытий; лента малярная; порожк;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/ddd/9dce0-5800-11e5-b9a9-00259036a192.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">клей для плитки; крестики; затирка; плиткорез;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/035/bae08-a7af-11e5-bed3-00259036a192.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">подложка; рулетка; набор для укладки ламината; лобзик; плинтус светлый; теплый пол под ламинат и паркет;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/b10/93417-8744-11e3-b1e6-00259036a114.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">клей для керамогранита; крестики; затирка для швов; плиткорез;; крестики для плитки; затирка для швов; плиткорез.;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/7d6/f5678-1c1b-11e6-b7ce-00259036a192.png"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">клей для плитки; крестики; затирка для швов; плиткорез; крестики; затирка для швов</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/cd9/e7427-20ec-11e6-95f7-00259036a192.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">клей для плитки; крестики; затирка для швов; плиткорез;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/87a/b5efd-3090-11e5-b9a9-00259036a192.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">клей для плитки; крестики; затирка для швов; плиткорез;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/291/e26a7-308f-11e5-b9a9-00259036a192.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">клей для плитки; крестики; затирка для швов; плиткорез;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/b9c/d2039-0a03-11e6-bed3-00259036a192.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">клей для плитки; крестики; затирка для швов; плиткорез;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/da4/4a45e-b9b7-11df-9b7f-001f29c68b0a.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">песок строительный; щебень фр.5-20; геотекстиль; уровень; резиновая киянка; лопата;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `flex`, а `.card-action` прибить к нижней части карточек абсолютом.

```css
.card_row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card_row>.col {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  padding-bottom: 71px;
}

.card_row .card .card-action {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
</head>

<body>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form class="col s12 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" novalidate="">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6"><input class="ng-tns-c40-0 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" data-length="10" id="input_text" name="str" type="text" ng-reflect-name="str"><label class="ng-tns-c40-0" for="input_text">search</label></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row card_row" style="transition: all 13s;">
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/d1b/98e1c-61c8-11e1-865f-00259036a114.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">клей для плитки; крестики; затирка для швов; плиткорез;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/9b5/7ac1c-02a7-11e5-afe5-00259036a192.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">рулетка; нож; клей Thomsit; клей для линолеума; клей для напольных покрытий; лента малярная; порожк;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/ddd/9dce0-5800-11e5-b9a9-00259036a192.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">клей для плитки; крестики; затирка; плиткорез;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/035/bae08-a7af-11e5-bed3-00259036a192.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">подложка; рулетка; набор для укладки ламината; лобзик; плинтус светлый; теплый пол под ламинат и паркет;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/b10/93417-8744-11e3-b1e6-00259036a114.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">клей для керамогранита; крестики; затирка для швов; плиткорез;; крестики для плитки; затирка для швов; плиткорез.;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/7d6/f5678-1c1b-11e6-b7ce-00259036a192.png"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">клей для плитки; крестики; затирка для швов; плиткорез; крестики; затирка для швов</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/cd9/e7427-20ec-11e6-95f7-00259036a192.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">клей для плитки; крестики; затирка для швов; плиткорез;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/87a/b5efd-3090-11e5-b9a9-00259036a192.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">клей для плитки; крестики; затирка для швов; плиткорез;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/291/e26a7-308f-11e5-b9a9-00259036a192.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">клей для плитки; крестики; затирка для швов; плиткорез;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/b9c/d2039-0a03-11e6-bed3-00259036a192.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">клей для плитки; крестики; затирка для швов; плиткорез;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col m12 l3 ng-tns-c40-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-appear ng-star-inserted" style="">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image"><img class="ng-tns-c40-0" src="https://tdp.ru/images/p/da4/4a45e-b9b7-11df-9b7f-001f29c68b0a.jpg"><span class="card-title"></span></div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="ng-tns-c40-0">песок строительный; щебень фр.5-20; геотекстиль; уровень; резиновая киянка; лопата;
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action"><a class="ng-tns-c40-0" href="#">link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```